# How to make Unity Web Player work on offline?

Tags: unity-game-engine, web-deployment, offline, unity-web-player

I'm trying to deploy my project on unity web player platform and I want to make it work on offline also.

I found several ways to do that but that doesn't work to me.

is there any way to do that?

Testing system environment
 - Windows 7
 - Internet Explorer 11

Comment: It does work offline. You just run the html which is on the local hard drive in your copy of IE and it works.
Can you elaborate.

Comment: 'Offline deployment' option checked. but it's not working.
kept showing 'Failed to update Unity Web Player'

Comment: Arrrr.. I solved problem. it's only work on pro license.. sorry!

Comment: @taesikyoon, how do you know that the unity web player will only work offline using the Pro License? Could you point me to a page online that says that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Unity Technologies employee [Schubkraft](http://answers.unity3d.com/users/67078/schubkraft.html), a special closed network license is required in order to run Unity while your system is not connected to the internet. [Here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1039750/how-to-make-unity-web-player-work-offline.html#answer-1039756) is the exchange where Schubkraft communicates this fact.